# C# client calling Java SOAP web service gets SAXException

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap

I have a C# service reference to a Java web service.  The soap that the client objects uses looks like:

`<s:Envelope ...><s:Body ...><requestArgument>...</requestArgument></s:Body></s:Envelope>`

It needs to look like:

`<s:Envelope ...><s:Body ...><methodName><requestArgument>...</requestArgument></methodName></s:Body></s:Envelope>`

How do I get the service reference to include the method name in the soap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your Java SOAP web service generate a WSDL.  With that, you should be able to create the correct C# client stubs and marshaling objects using the [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx) tool

Comment: The server author modified his web service and WSDL, and it's working now.  Thanks!